# Read XML Node in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

I'm writing an assembly in VB.NET which will connect to a rest web service, call the contents in XML and upon being returned I want to specifically grab the contents and write it to a file.  I'm new at this and looking to get the contents of the column1 node and write it into a text file.

The XML looks like this:

```
<p5:test xmlns:p5="http://www.myapp.com/database/test">
<row>
<column1>test</column1>
</row>
<row>
<column1>Test2</column1>
</row>
</p5:test>
```

Can anyone provide an example of how I may do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it.Hope that is helps.

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
            Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim str As String
            Dim fs As New FileStream("YourFileName.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            xmldoc.Load(fs)
            xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("column1")
            For i = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1
                xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
                str += xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() 
    Next

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", str);
```